# How to conditionally create terraform resources and stop deletion in the next apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this scenario where I need to make sure if an `aws` `lambda` exists, if does, stop creating it with terraform, so I used `count` with conditional rendering as below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_aurora_hibernation" {

  count         = var.is_lambda_exist == "exist" ? 0 : 1

  filename      = "lambda_function.zip"
  function_name = "lambda-aurora-hibernation"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler       = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda_function.zip")
  runtime = "python3.6"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_aurora_hibernation_permission" {

  count     = length(aws_lambda_function.lambda_aurora_hibernation)

  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.lambda_aurora_hibernation[count.index].function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda_aurora_hibernation_event_rule.arn
  depends_on=[aws_lambda_function.lambda_aurora_hibernation]
}
```

The value of the variable `is_lambda_exist` in the first `terraform apply` is `not_exists` and therefore the value for the `count` becomes `1`, which is correct.

And in the next `terraform apply` I change the value of the `is_lambda_exist` to `exist` and the then the value of the `count` becomes `0` **which will result in the deletion of the resources**

> The reason why I do this is there can be resources manually created by someone, so if that lambda is already exists by some other mean, needs to stop creating it

How can I prevent this? Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a count on the resource at all. The default count is one. As stated in their docs:

> By default, a resource block configures one real infrastructure object.

(https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html)

I think you've misunderstood a core tenet of Terraform, which is that it is *declarative*.

That means if it has created a resource once, subsequent runs of `apply` will not create another resource in the same shape, unless the resource definition has changed such that it cannot be updated in-place, and then it will destroy the existing resource and create a new one in its place.

So unless you set `count` to larger than one, you will only ever have one of a resource.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_aurora_hibernation" {
  filename         = "lambda_function.zip"
  function_name    = "lambda-aurora-hibernation"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda_function.zip")
  runtime          = "python3.6"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_aurora_hibernation_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_aurora_hibernation.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda_aurora_hibernation_event_rule.arn
  depends_on    = [aws_lambda_function.lambda_aurora_hibernation]
}
```

Comment: The reason why i do this is there can be resources manually created by someone, so if that lambda is already exists by some other mean, needs to stop creating it

Comment: If that happens, you can import the resource into your TF state using the `terraform import` command: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html